# Search bar styling appears locally but not on heroku

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a custom search bar that displays correctly when run locally but not when deployed to heroku.

Locally the bar has an off-black background with grey text but the deployed version looks like the default HTML search bar (and it's smaller so it displays in the top left corner of the search-wrap div.

I'm fairly certain this is a load order issue.

Here is the html.erb:

```
<aside class="library-search">
  <%= form_tag(library_movements_path, method: "get") do %>
    <div class="search-wrap"><%= text_field_tag(:q, nil, placeholder: 'Search by name', value: @query) %></div>
    <%= submit_tag("") %>
  <% end %>
</aside>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.library-search {
  margin: 0 13.081395348837% 33px 9.302325581395%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  form              { display: block; width: 100%; position: relative; height: 33px; }
 .search-wrap      { width: auto; height: 100%; margin-right: 32px; border-right: 1px solid black; }
input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 2px 8px 0;
  height: 100%;
  font: normal 16px/1.1 $rajmedium; // I know, I know; I'd DRY and em-size if I could. But search fields are stupid.
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 }
input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: image-url("icons-ui/magnifying-glass.svg") no-repeat 7px 7px;
  background-size: 17px 17px;
  background-color: $color-voltred;
  width: 32px;
  height: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
  &:hover         { @include subtlehover($color-voltred); }
 }
}//.library-search
```

Comment: Stupid question, but what if you compile the SASS and put the resulting CSS on the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a workaround for this - thank you Mr Lister for getting me pointed in the right direction. I played around with compiling it locally and testing it that way which led me to my fix.

For some reason the compiled version of the html.erb was not rendering the input type tag with the rest of the input tags. All the other tags were there EXCEPT type.

So, I added a "movement-search" class as an option to the text_field_tag and changed the SASS from input[type="text"] to .movement-search which solved the problem.

Not sure why the compiled version wouldn't include the input type tag but that's for another question.